# Updating kendo dataSource via transport

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox, kendo-dropdown

I'm trying to set the remote data url based on the selected value from another dropdownlist (cboSearchString1DDL.element[0].value). I continue to learn the Kendo web controls so I'm not sure how to most efficiently complete this task. I tried a couple avenues but still am getting an error when the dataSource is read. I'm trying to set it onclose of DDL1. Here's where I'm at, I know it's not the correct way:

```
// search string 1 DDL
var cboSearchString1DDL = $("#cboSearchString1DDL").kendoDropDownList({
    autoBind: false,
    optionLabel: " "
}).data("kendoDropDownList");

// search string 2 DDL
var cboSearchString2DDL = $("#cboSearchString2DDL").kendoDropDownList({
    autoBind: false,
    optionLabel: " "    
}).data("kendoDropDownList");

// 1st DDL dataSource                   
var dataSourceTowns = new kendo.data.DataSource({                   
    transport: {       
       read: {
           url: _urlTowns,
           dataType: "json",
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: "Towns"
    }
});

$("#cboSearchString1DDL").data("kendoDropDownList").wrapper.show();

// 1st DDL                               
var townsDDL = $("#cboSearchString1DDL").kendoDropDownList({
    autoBind: false,
    dataTextField: "Column1",
    dataValueField: "Column1",
    dataSource: dataSourceTowns,
    close: function () {
        alert(cboSearchString1DDL.element[0].value);
        streetsDDL.enable(true);
        streetsDDL.setDataSource(dataSourcestreetsDDL);
        streetsDDL.refresh();
    }
}).data("kendoDropDownList");

// show 2nd DDL 
$("#cboSearchString2DDL").data("kendoDropDownList").wrapper.show();
cboSearchString2DDL.enable(false);

// 2nd DDL datasource 
var dataSourcestreetsDDL = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: _urlSOESearchAddress + "townName=" + cboSearchString1DDL.element[0].value + "&f=",
        dataType: "json",
        },
    },
    schema: {
        data: "StreetsinTown"
    }
});

// 2nd DDL
var streetsDDL = $("#cboSearchString2DDL").kendoDropDownList({
    autoBind: false,
    dataTextField: "Street",
    dataValueField: "Street",
    requestStart: function (e) {
        console.log("request started");
    },
    requestEnd: function (e) {
        var response = e.response;
        var type = e.type;
        console.log(type);
        console.log(response.length);
    }
}).data("kendoDropDownList");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: cboSearchString1DDL.element[0].value is apparently null when the remote service call takes place. Thanks.

Comment: Well it's certainly not defined in the code you posted. So define it or post more of your code.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've updated my code with brevity in mind.

Comment: cboSearchString1DDL is still not defined anywhere.  Are you getting jquery selector mixed up with variable names?

Comment: My guess is that you should be doing something like this: `$('#cboSearchString1DDL').val()` instead of `cboSearchString1DDL.element[0].value`

Comment: OK, now I see what's up with that var.  And you are trying to get the value of the drop down selection to put in the url correct?

Comment: Thanks, the controls are defined earlier in project, I added them in my code. I was getting a successful value for cboSearchString1DDL.element[0].value and $('#cboSearchString1DDL').val() in a close method on townsDDL. However, it is still breaking when you click DDL2 (open). [scratching my head...].

Comment: yes (on your previous comment), thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the url can be a function that returns the URL as a string. So if it is easier to code, you could also do something like:

```
var dataSourcestreetsDDL = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: function () {
                var searchAddress = ...;
                var searchString = ...;
                return searchAddress + "townName=" + searchString + "&f=";
            }
        ...
```

The function will be called whenever the datasource needs to read data. It might be easier than changing things when the dropdown closes.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. A virtual beer for you! That worked out just great.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#cboSearchString1DDL").kendoDropDownList({
```

is called twice.  Second time it's called it probably wipes out the var set here:

```
var cboSearchString1DDL = $("#cboSearchString1DDL").kendoDropDownList({
```

Usually with kendo if you are going to initialize a component more than once on an element, you'll need to perform a .destroy() to do it cleanly.  I'm not even sure that this is what you are trying to do though.

Comment: I am reusing the element, you're correct. I have a large case statement where I use a .hide() and .show() to swap out AutoComplete or a DropDownList control. I'll look into the .destroy() and when to call it. The documentation is very brief.

Comment: One other thing... I had a dynamic list I wanted to use in a kendo drop down in my Kendo grid.  It seemed like the drop down only built itself at the time it was clicked. I was using this in the filter drop down area.  I ended up having to detect mousedown, build list, and have a callback in the kendo drop down to the results of my dynamic list.  May or may not help.  Hard to tell since there are so many possibilities with Kendo.

Comment: Ouch, I know. I'm always learning something new with these controls. Somewhat frustrating like my issue above, especially when I can trap the control showing me the value, yet breaks. I'm looking into .destroy(). Sounds like a fun method to use at this point ;)